# escaping hypen in python 2.7 when using subprocess to run a shell command on a linux environment

Tags: python

I took some's help from here to get to this code

```
command="pidstat -ruht"
#command="pidstat"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = process.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':
    os.write(1, line)
  else:
    break
```

this code does not work, no matter how i escape - as "pidstat -ruht" or "pidstat \-ruht"
tried few other combinations also using `, ' , etc for escaping (based on some other forums)

Could someone please help?
Also, plz point to a good beginner book for learning python.

Comment: Try `process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` to run it through the shell.

Comment: brill, it worked, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't use `shell=True` to solve all the problems. It is less secure when using user supplied arguments. Instead give the command line as a list: `command = ['pidstat', '-ruht']`

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` can run a program with or without shell processing. By default, `Popen` expects a command list and skips the shell. You can override that with the `shell` parameter. Either of these will work:

```
command = ["pidstat", "-ruht"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or

```
command="pidstat -ruht"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If you want to do shell processing on the command line (e.g., variable substitution, piping to other commands, etc...) then you either have to stick to the `shell=True` version or figure out the python equivalent.

You can also change your while loop to

```
for line in process.stdout:
    os.write(1, line)
```